# Como enviar um vídeo via POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Tenho uma aplicação que está sendo escrita em Node.js e utilizando o Electron, preciso enviar um vídeo no formato mp4 via POST para o servidor. Como posso fazer isso?

**EDIT 1:**

Na aplicação, uso o FFmpeg para criar um vídeo de cinco minutos a partir da webcam. Preciso enviar este vídeo para o servidor usando uma requisição POST, o que quero saber é se há um jeito de enviar este arquivo usando essa requisição. Seja diretamente, codificando ele de alguma forma, transformando em binário ou de outra maneira qualquer.

Comment: Enviar um video via `POST`? explique isso melhor

Comment: Editei a pergunta tentando explicar melhor.

Comment: Você não vai enviar o video, você vai fazer upload do video e caso (caso queira) for salvar no banco, vai pegar o nome e extensão e salvar. Só isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o módulo `request` para realizar a operação, e `createReadStream` para ler o arquivo local em modo binário:

```
    const request = require("request");

    request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://www.servidor.com/upload",
            formData: { 
                       upload_type: "txt", 
                       file: fs.createReadStream("/folder/arquivo.txt") }
        },
        function(err, response, body) { console.log(err, response, body) });
```

Fontes:

- https://github.com/request/request
- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream

Comment: Me ajudou muito, o que preciso agora é acrescentar um parâmetro inteiro no corpo da requisição. "testeId": "01234". Como proceder?

Comment: @lys - acredito que você pode simplesmente adicionar a propriedade ao objeto enviado. Assim: `formdata: { testId: '01234', upload_type: 'txt',` [...]